# Smooth animation in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to create smooth animation on the header logo of my website.(http://sh003.global.temp.domains/~tharavad/)

I use Elementor Page Builder and OceanWP Theme.

I have created the header using header footer plugin for Elementor.After adding the image section, CSS code added to get the sliding effect, but not able to get it be very smooth..,like there is slide down effect.

Code that I tried with is ('myclass' is the CSS class I have set on my image column):

```
.myclass {
   animation: mymove 5s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes mymove {
   from {top: 20px;}
   to {bottom: 50px;}   
}
```

Comment: Try using the same attribute in from and to.  Like, choose top or bottom.  If that doesn't work, try creating a minimal working example (snippet).

Comment: thanks much.Your suggestion worked, posting the answer for the benefit of others.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the smooth animation to work, as suggested by thingEvery.
I have changed the CSS to the same attribute on the from and to as below.

```
.myclass{
  animation: mymove 7s infinite ease-in-out;

}
@keyframes mymove {
  from {top: -90px;}
  to {top: 20px;}

}
```